# 0.1 +0.1... 10 times != 1 in R

Tags: r

If I sum 0.1, 10 times in R why does it not equal 1?

e.g

```
0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 1
```

returns

```
FALSE
```

However

```
0.1 * 10 ==1
```

returns

```
TRUE
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: I don't know if it's related here but whenever there is a question related to floating point it is somehow always linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: and as mentioned `all.equal(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1,1)` gives `#[1] TRUE`